# Issue with query method for one click translating from html data-* attributes

Tags: jquery, html

So I'm trying to implement a way to translate content in my page without refreshing it using the meaty html5 data-* attributes, in this case data-en to store the english translated text. I am translating from spanish to english.

What my code does, OR should do since it doesn't work:

-Store all p elements with data attribute "data-en".
-Cicle throught the p elements with for.
-storin the value of "data-en" into a variable "trans".
-replacing the text of the p element with "trans" variabe.

Here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var i = 0;
var trans;
$('.settingswheel').click(function(){
atraducir = $('p[data-en]');
for (i = 0; i < atraducir.length; i++) {
  trans = atraducir[i].text(atraducir[i].data('en'));
  atraducir[i].text(trans);      
}
});
});
```

```css
.memory{display:none; width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;}

.currentmemory{display:block;}

 .postit {
  position:absolute; 
  overflow:hidden;
  left:1070px; 
  top:-155px; 
  padding-left:10px;
  line-height: 1;   
  width: 275px;    
  margin: 0px;    
  min-height:250px;
  max-height:250px;
  padding-top:35px; 
  border:1px solid #E8E8E8;  
  border-top:60px solid #fdfd86;
  font-family:'Reenie Beanie';    
  font-size:22px;      
  border-bottom-right-radius: 60px 5px;
  display:inline-block;    
  background: #ffff88; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ffff88 81%, #ffff88 82%, #ffff88 82%, #ffffc6 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(81%,#ffff88), color-stop(82%,#ffff88), color-stop(82%,#ffff88), color-stop(100%,#ffffc6)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ffff88 81%,#ffff88 82%,#ffff88 82%,#ffffc6 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ffff88 81%,#ffff88 82%,#ffff88 82%,#ffffc6 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ffff88 81%,#ffff88 82%,#ffff88 82%,#ffffc6 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #ffff88 81%,#ffff88 82%,#ffff88 82%,#ffffc6 100%); /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffff88', endColorstr='#ffffc6',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}
 
.postit:after {     
  content: "";
  position:absolute; 
  z-index:-1;
  right:-0px; bottom:20px;
  width:200px;
  height: 25px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow:2px 15px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40);
  -moz-transform: matrix(-1, -0.1, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: matrix(-1, -0.1, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: matrix(-1, -0.1, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: matrix(-1, -0.1, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  transform: matrix(-1, -0.1, 0, 1, 0, 0);
}

.settingswheel{
 position:absolute; 
 bottom:22px; 
 right:15px; 
 cursor:pointer;
 z-index:10001;
 -moz-transition: transform 2.5s;
    -webkit-transition: transform 2.5s;
    transition: transform 2.5s;
}

.settingswheel:hover{
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
}

.settingsin{z-index:2; font-size:60px; font-family: 'Covered By Your Grace', cursive;  display:flex; justify-content:flex-start; align-items:center; height:80px; width:200px;  background-color:rgb(255, 255, 136); position:absolute; bottom:5px; left:5px; transition: all 1.5s ease;}
.settingsout{z-index:2; font-size:60px; font-family: 'Covered By Your Grace', cursive;  display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center; padding:15px; background-color:rgb(255, 255, 136); position:absolute; bottom:5px; left:-202px; transition: all 1.5s ease;}

.menu{
 list-style:none; 
 bottom:8px; 
 position:absolute; 
 font-family: 'Covered By Your Grace', cursive; 
 font-weight:300; 
 width:200px;
 z-index:1;
}

.menu ul li{font-size:22px; margin-top:8px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="postit">
  <img class="settingswheel" src="images/settings.png">
  <span class="settingsin" data-en="Settings">Ajustes</span>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li data-en="Full screen">Pantalla completa:  <span id="fullscreentoggler" value="F" onclick="toggleFullScreen()" data-en="yes">si</span></li>
 <li data-en="Language">Idioma:  <span id="languagetoggler" onclick="toggleLanguage()" >español</span></li>
 <li data-en="Slides">Diapositivas:  <span class="resta">< </span><span class="segundos">5s</span><span class="suma"> ></span></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="memories1container" style="width:550px; height:600px; position:relative; top:42px; left:70px; transform: rotate(-1deg); ">
    <div class="memory fade currentmemory" style="">
   <div class="p1" style="background-image: url('images/IMG-20170902-WA0031.jpg');"><div class="pin1"></div><div class="pin2"></div><div class="pin3"></div><div class="pin4"></div></div>
   <div class="p2" style="background-image: url('images/IMG-20170610-WA0040.jpg');"><div class="pin1"></div><div class="pin2"></div><div class="pin3"></div><div class="pin4"></div></div>
   <p data-mem="1" data-en="Walking with my churri through the gigantic streets of Washington, District of Columbia hehehe. Anda mujer! we are a couple of the most beautiful ..." style="">Paseando con mi churri por las calles gigaaaantes de Washington, Distrito de Columbia jejeje. Anda mujer! pero si somos una pareja de lo mas guapetona...</p>
   <p data-mem="2" data-en="specially TWO !" style="">especialmente TÚ !</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: atraducir[i].data is not a function` - Use chrome inspector to find errors, then fix them.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `.text(fn)`

```
$('.settingswheel').click(function () {
    $('p[data-en]').text(function () {
        return $(this).data('en');
    });
});
```

Here in snippet, I have used a `<BUTTON>` to attach `click` event handler.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.settingswheel').click(function() {
    $('p[data-en]').text(function() {
      return $(this).data('en');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.memory {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.currentmemory {
  display: block;
}

.postit {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 1070px;
  top: -155px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  line-height: 1;
  width: 275px;
  margin: 0px;
  min-height: 250px;
  max-height: 250px;
  padding-top: 35px;
  border: 1px solid #E8E8E8;
  border-top: 60px solid #fdfd86;
  font-family: 'Reenie Beanie';
  font-size: 22px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 60px 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ffff88;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ffff88 81%, #ffff88 82%, #ffff88 82%, #ffffc6 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(81%, #ffff88), color-stop(82%, #ffff88), color-stop(82%, #ffff88), color-stop(100%, #ffffc6));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ffff88 81%, #ffff88 82%, #ffff88 82%, #ffffc6 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ffff88 81%, #ffff88 82%, #ffff88 82%, #ffffc6 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ffff88 81%, #ffff88 82%, #ffff88 82%, #ffffc6 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #ffff88 81%, #ffff88 82%, #ffff88 82%, #ffffc6 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffff88', endColorstr='#ffffc6', GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}

.postit:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  right: -0px;
  bottom: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 25px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 2px 15px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40);
  -moz-transform: matrix(-1, -0.1, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: matrix(-1, -0.1, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: matrix(-1, -0.1, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: matrix(-1, -0.1, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  transform: matrix(-1, -0.1, 0, 1, 0, 0);
}

.settingswheel {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 22px;
  right: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 10001;
  -moz-transition: transform 2.5s;
  -webkit-transition: transform 2.5s;
  transition: transform 2.5s;
}

.settingswheel:hover {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
}

.settingsin {
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: 'Covered By Your Grace', cursive;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  height: 80px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 136);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  transition: all 1.5s ease;
}

.settingsout {
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: 'Covered By Your Grace', cursive;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 136);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: -202px;
  transition: all 1.5s ease;
}

.menu {
  list-style: none;
  bottom: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Covered By Your Grace', cursive;
  font-weight: 300;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu ul li {
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-top: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="settingswheel">settingswheel</button>
<div class="postit">

  <span class="settingsin" data-en="Settings">Ajustes</span>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li data-en="Full screen">Pantalla completa: <span id="fullscreentoggler" value="F" onclick="toggleFullScreen()" data-en="yes">si</span></li>
    <li data-en="Language">Idioma: <span id="languagetoggler" onclick="toggleLanguage()">español</span></li>
    <li data-en="Slides">Diapositivas: <span class="resta">< </span><span class="segundos">5s</span><span class="suma"> ></span></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="memories1container" style="width:550px; height:600px; position:relative; top:42px; left:70px; transform: rotate(-1deg); ">
  <div class="memory fade currentmemory" style="">
    <div class="p1" style="background-image: url('images/IMG-20170902-WA0031.jpg');">
      <div class="pin1"></div>
      <div class="pin2"></div>
      <div class="pin3"></div>
      <div class="pin4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="p2" style="background-image: url('images/IMG-20170610-WA0040.jpg');">
      <div class="pin1"></div>
      <div class="pin2"></div>
      <div class="pin3"></div>
      <div class="pin4"></div>
    </div>
    <p data-mem="1" data-en="Walking with my churri through the gigantic streets of Washington, District of Columbia hehehe. Anda mujer! we are a couple of the most beautiful ..." style="">Paseando con mi churri por las calles gigaaaantes de Washington, Distrito de Columbia jejeje. Anda mujer! pero si somos una pareja de lo mas guapetona...</p>
    <p data-mem="2" data-en="specially TWO !" style="">especialmente TÚ !</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Use `.eq(index)` to access element at index then `.data()` and `.text()` can be used.

```
$('.settingswheel').click(function () {
    atraducir = $('p[data-en]');
    for (i = 0; i < atraducir.length; i++) {
        var elem = atraducir.eq(i); //Get element at index
        trans = elem.data('en'); //Get Data
        elem.text(trans); //Set text
    }
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 0;
  var trans;
  $('.settingswheel').click(function() {
    atraducir = $('p[data-en]');
    for (i = 0; i < atraducir.length; i++) {
    var elem = atraducir.eq(i);
      trans = elem.data('en');
      elem.text(trans);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.memory {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.currentmemory {
  display: block;
}

.postit {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 1070px;
  top: -155px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  line-height: 1;
  width: 275px;
  margin: 0px;
  min-height: 250px;
  max-height: 250px;
  padding-top: 35px;
  border: 1px solid #E8E8E8;
  border-top: 60px solid #fdfd86;
  font-family: 'Reenie Beanie';
  font-size: 22px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 60px 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ffff88;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ffff88 81%, #ffff88 82%, #ffff88 82%, #ffffc6 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(81%, #ffff88), color-stop(82%, #ffff88), color-stop(82%, #ffff88), color-stop(100%, #ffffc6));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ffff88 81%, #ffff88 82%, #ffff88 82%, #ffffc6 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ffff88 81%, #ffff88 82%, #ffff88 82%, #ffffc6 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ffff88 81%, #ffff88 82%, #ffff88 82%, #ffffc6 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #ffff88 81%, #ffff88 82%, #ffff88 82%, #ffffc6 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffff88', endColorstr='#ffffc6', GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}

.postit:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  right: -0px;
  bottom: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 25px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 2px 15px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40);
  -moz-transform: matrix(-1, -0.1, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: matrix(-1, -0.1, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: matrix(-1, -0.1, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: matrix(-1, -0.1, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  transform: matrix(-1, -0.1, 0, 1, 0, 0);
}

.settingswheel {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 22px;
  right: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 10001;
  -moz-transition: transform 2.5s;
  -webkit-transition: transform 2.5s;
  transition: transform 2.5s;
}

.settingswheel:hover {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
}

.settingsin {
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: 'Covered By Your Grace', cursive;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  height: 80px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 136);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  transition: all 1.5s ease;
}

.settingsout {
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: 'Covered By Your Grace', cursive;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 136);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: -202px;
  transition: all 1.5s ease;
}

.menu {
  list-style: none;
  bottom: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Covered By Your Grace', cursive;
  font-weight: 300;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu ul li {
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-top: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="settingswheel">settingswheel</button>
<div class="postit">

  <span class="settingsin" data-en="Settings">Ajustes</span>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li data-en="Full screen">Pantalla completa: <span id="fullscreentoggler" value="F" onclick="toggleFullScreen()" data-en="yes">si</span></li>
    <li data-en="Language">Idioma: <span id="languagetoggler" onclick="toggleLanguage()">español</span></li>
    <li data-en="Slides">Diapositivas: <span class="resta">< </span><span class="segundos">5s</span><span class="suma"> ></span></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="memories1container" style="width:550px; height:600px; position:relative; top:42px; left:70px; transform: rotate(-1deg); ">
  <div class="memory fade currentmemory" style="">
    <div class="p1" style="background-image: url('images/IMG-20170902-WA0031.jpg');">
      <div class="pin1"></div>
      <div class="pin2"></div>
      <div class="pin3"></div>
      <div class="pin4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="p2" style="background-image: url('images/IMG-20170610-WA0040.jpg');">
      <div class="pin1"></div>
      <div class="pin2"></div>
      <div class="pin3"></div>
      <div class="pin4"></div>
    </div>
    <p data-mem="1" data-en="Walking with my churri through the gigantic streets of Washington, District of Columbia hehehe. Anda mujer! we are a couple of the most beautiful ..." style="">Paseando con mi churri por las calles gigaaaantes de Washington, Distrito de Columbia jejeje. Anda mujer! pero si somos una pareja de lo mas guapetona...</p>
    <p data-mem="2" data-en="specially TWO !" style="">especialmente TÚ !</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.settingswheel').click(function(){
        atraducir = $('p[data-en]');

        for (i = 0; i < atraducir.length; i++) {
            atraducir[i].innerText = atraducir[i].dataset.en
        }
    });
});
```